# Form login and post parameters by curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to login into R-studio in order to grab (curl) an image. 
I use the procedure as below, but it does not return the image, just the form itself.
This is the location of the form: 
http://skiweather.eu:8787/auth-sign-in

```
    <?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'XXX';
$loginUrl = 'http://skiweather.eu:8787/auth-do-sign-in';
$sign=1;
$cookie= "cookies.txt";

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName("meta");
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $tokens->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token')
    $token = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

$postinfo = 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&staySignedIn=1&appUri='.$loginUrl.'&_csrf='.$token;
echo $token; //debug info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);


//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://skiweather.eu:8787/files/R/devel/PLOTS/snowalert_today_0.png');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//save the data to disk
file_put_contents('pppp.png', $content);

?>
```

Comment: You didn't give any username and password? Also, this doesn't seem like a proper API and rather an exploitation attempt of the login through sign in form page using cURL.

Comment: first off you need to get a cookie session BEFORE sending the login request, then you need to fetch a csrf token from `http://skiweather.eu:8787/auth-public-key` BEFORE sending the login request, then you need to send the actual login request (with both the cookie and the token) to `http://skiweather.eu:8787/auth-do-sign-in` but you're sending the login request to `http://skiweather.eu:8787/auth-sign-in` , that's where you get the login cookie, it's not where you're supposed to send the actual login request. you're doing lots of things wrong here